# Trigger to update another table to refer top most row in updated table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

This is my **Meter** Table.

```
MeterID int
LatestMeterReadingID int refers MeterReading
```

**MeterReadingTable**

```
MeterID int
MeterReadingID int
Reading bigint
ForDate date
isInactive bit
```

I want a trigger on the meter reading table to put the latest meter reading on the meter table when updated / inserted

1. New meter reading
2. Update Existing meter reading, date or meter (affects old meter too) or Inactivate meter reading

I also want the higher meter reading if the dates are equal.

I have done this via my ORM but want to transfer this logic to the database. I can do the insert part of it but not sure how to handle the update.

By top most I mean this

```
 Where isInactive=0 Order By ForDate DESC, Reading DESC
```

Comment: It sounds like `Meter` could be replaced by a *view* with those columns. Why do you need to *store* the information about which is the latest reading rather than *calculate* it?

Comment: It's faster when reporting on 1000+ meters? Running top 1 on that query 1000 times would be slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need. It may need some tweaking:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.MeterReadingTrigger 
   ON  dbo.MeterReading 
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

  ;WITH cte AS
  (
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MeterID ORDER BY MeterID, ForDate DESC, Reading DESC) AS Row,
      mr.MeterID,
      mr.MeterReadingID,
      mr.Reading,
      mr.ForDate,
      mr.IsInactive
    FROM
      dbo.MeterReading AS mr
    JOIN Inserted i ON mr.MeterId = i.MeterID
    WHERE
      mr.IsInactive = 0        
  )
  UPDATE m
   SET m.LatestMeterReadingId = cte.MeterReadingId
  FROM
    cte JOIN
    INSERTED i 
      ON cte.MeterID = i.MeterId
    JOIN Meter m
      ON m.MeterID = i.MeterId
  WHERE
    Row = 1


END
GO
```

Answer updated with a JOIN to INSERTED in the CTE.

Comment: Can you explain to me how it updates the meter table if I set the isInactive flag to 1 on an existing row or how it works if I change the meterID on an existing row. Shouldn't it update 2 rows in the Meter table in the latter case?

Comment: @Dasiths. Did you bother to test this answer? I have tested the trigger and it correctly updates the meter table with the latest "active" MeterReadingID. As far as your second question, I can update the answer to do this, but it seems an unusual thing to do: that is update the MeterID!

Comment: Sorry if it came out rude. I would like to know how it works. Like why the use of partitions and some comments so I can learn and reuse it later on for other triggers. As for the second part of the question. Consider I'm updating a row where MeterID was 1 to 2. Shouldn't it update the latest meter reading for both meter 1 and 2 considering both of those meters could be affected?

Comment: After doing some more reading on how the partition and row_number() works I have come to the understanding that the trigger updates all meters on the table? Please correct me if I'm wrong. Would it not have an undesired performance impact? I will accept this as the answer as it works but would I be better served to just do it via the ORM for only the specific meters that need updating?

Comment: Notice that the MeterReading table is joined to the INSERTED virtual table which is automatically available inside a trigger (as well as a DELETED table). The INSERTED table has a row for each MeterReading row that was updated. We also JOIN the Meter table to INSERTED ON MeterID. That means that only Meters that need updating are referenced. So the performance impact is minimised.

Comment: BTW. I agree with the comment from @Damien_The_Unbeliever that a view is probably a better solution for a number of reasons. One being that if you change the logic behind your requirement no data updates would be needed. If you have the appropriate indexes in place the performance would be instant for the number of rows you have mentioned. This would mean that the Meter table is unnecessary. Lets say the view was called "Meters_View" then all you would need to do is SELECT * FROM Meters_view. If you like I will add another answer that uses a view. That would deal with the 2nd problem as well.